# Negative correlation between interest rates and credit spreads - Why?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, spread, credit

In fixed income markets a stylized fact seems to be that there is a negative correlation between interest rates and credit spreads: Spreads tend to widen as rates fall. Why is that?

Comment: http://www.citibank.com/ipb/europe/pdfs/monthly_0313.pdf